# sorl-thumbnail in Django admin using AdminImageMixin

Tags: django-admin, sorl-thumbnail

I'm trying to use [sorl-thumbnail v11.12](http://sorl-thumbnail.readthedocs.org/en/latest/examples.html) to display thumbnails in the Django admin.

My `models.py` already uses sorl.thumbnail.ImageField as per the docs:

```
Note You do not need to use the sorl.thumbnail.ImageField to use sorl.thumbnail. The standard django.db.models.ImageField is fine except that using the sorl.thumbnail.ImageField lets you plugin the nice admin addition explained in the next section.
```

However, I am unsure how to configure the `admin.py`. I've already done a `manage.py syncdb`. Currently, I have the following, but it is not displaying the thumbnails in Django admin.

**MyProject/admin.py**

```
from django.contrib.admin import *
from sorl.thumbnail.admin import AdminImageMixin

class ModelAdmin(AdminImageMixin, ModelAdmin):
    pass

class TabularInline(AdminImageMixin, TabularInline):
    pass

class StackedInline(AdminImageMixin, StackedInline):
    pass
```

**MyProject/myapp/admin.py**

```
from MyProject import admin
from myapp.models import Tours

class ToursAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'image', 'price')
    search_fields = ('name',)

admin.site.register(Tours, ToursAdmin)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
# models.py
class Tours(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="path/")

    def thumb(self):
        return u'<img src="%s" />' % (get_thumbnail(c, "50x50", crop='center', quality=95).url)
    thumbs.short_description = 'Photos'
    thumbs.allow_tags = True

# admin.py
class ToursAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'thumb', 'price')
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation as to how this code works.  Code dumping is usually discouraged and frowned upon here on StackOverflow

Comment: in Django 3.1 this does not work anymore (we found that after a major platform upgrade). The HTML tags are processed as "not safe": &lt; &gt;

Comment: The solution for Django 2+ is to use return mark_safe('<img.....